# How to register newly mounted drive in git bash?

Tags: windows, git, bash, mount, drive

In my day-to-day work (I'm using MS Windows), I keep my git bash (actually using [console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) for this) open for the whole day. It is also very frequent that I mount new drives that I would like to work with git. 
However I noticed that I need to exit the bash and open it again in order to make it recognize new drive letter.

Is there any command that 'registers' already mounted drive in git bash ?
thanks

edit2: 
I do not have any option to left a comment under my own question (weird ..?), so I post it here:

```
$ mount -a
sh.exe": mount: command not found
```

Comment: When you say "drive letter" that implies Windows. Is that the case? I guess "console2" also implies that.

Comment: Have you tried doing `mount -a` ?

Comment: Yes, the Windows port of git is built on top of the `msys` emulation later (similar in spirit to Cygwin, but a distinct implementation).  `msys` has its own way of representing Windows drives; for example, what Windows calls `C:\`, msys calls `/c` (and Cygwin calls `/cygwin/c`).  Apparently mounting a new Windows drive, say `X:\`, doesn't automatically make it visible as `/X`.

Comment: I actually have the same problem. I have my work-in-progress in a Truecrypt file. If I start git bash first, and then mount the Truecrypt file to, say, `Y:`, I am unable to do `cd /y`.

Comment: I get, just as OP, the result:
`sh.exe": mount: command not found`

Comment: I made GitBash work with a truecrypt file mounted as a drive in Windows using the context menu of Windows Explorer. Select a directory on that drive and call "Git Bash Here" from the context menu.

Comment: See this answer (it suggests to mount the drive as a folder on drive C:) http://superuser.com/questions/342534/mount-external-drive-on-windows7-for-git

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Couple of things, had some difficulty finding sources so feel free to take it with a grain of salt.

1. Msysgit simply doesn't include a version of `mount`. It is my understanding that [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) does, however. There is no simple way to either view all attached drives or mount a new drive in msys, and thus Git Bash.

To answer your question, you don't: Git Bash does not dynamically assign drives, so if you mount new drives, you need to close all instances and restart Git Bash ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/342534/mount-external-drive-on-windows7-for-git)). The source referenced there is cached [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LJzsR8-KgykJ:comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/13133+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). Sorry there's not a nicer solution.

Comment: Closing ALL instances was the key. I tried restarting git bash, but it didn't work because I had another window open.

Comment: Closing all instances, and restarting Git Bash did not work for me. The reason might be that I am mounting Truecrypt images instead of physical drives.

Comment: I had to go into the Task manager and look for all `git.exe` and `sh.exe` processes.  Even though I had closed all the windows, I had a few lingering processes that needed to be removed.

Comment: For me it didn't work until except for sh.exe I also killed ssh-agent.exe, which the first Git Bash window had initiated.

Answer (score 0):

I commonly mount a drive to the file system and then have to run a script that alters some files on the from within a Git Bash session in Console 2.

If you mount something to a given drive letter, say F: on the Windows file system, and then start the Git Bash session it will have it mapped. I can mount/unmount the F: drive and the session can still access /f/ without any issues. So, mount all the drives you will typically need to hit and then start the session and hopefully you don't need to restart your Git Bash too often.

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I exit all currently running git bash sessions and then launch a new one, then I can access the new drive, e.g. X:, in the new bash session under `/x/`.

Even launching a new git bash session is not enough if there was already one running; I must exit the previous git bash sessions and then launch one for it to make the new drive letters available.

Answer (score -1):

I found that if I set

MSYS_WATCH_FSTAB=YesPlease

in my User Environment variables. Then everything worked.